# ASP.Net State Server Fault Tolerance

Tags: asp.net-2.0, session-state

Can a State server in ASP.Net be made fault tolerant? By that I mean is when one state server goes down, ASP.Net applications can switch to another state server.

I do not want to go to a Database based state management as that seems considerably slower than the State Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure two different servers in fail over cluster i.e. if one server goes down due to some issue, other server will get up. For details see:-

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731844%28WS.10%29.aspx

When you configure your servers in fail over mode then a virtual IP is given to you which you will use as your state server's IP.

Also have a look at peer to peer state server as well:-

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/p2pstateserver.aspx